# Programmatically fire MouseEvent/KeyEvent

Tags: java, mouse, emulation

I am attempting to programatically emulate a mouseclick/keypress. By that I mean telling the application that the mouse or key has been pressed, but not having my mouse actually be clicked in windows.

I have tried many things up to now and none of them have succeeded in doing what I wish. I attempted to use `processMouseMotionEvent` which did nothing when I fed it `MouseEvent`s and I've tried `dispatchEvent` which also did nothing of use.

What can I do to emulate a simple mouse click/key press?

This is what I have right now, though it doesn't do anything.

(`j` is a WebBrowser component from DJSwing)

```
j.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(j, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 2, false));
```

Comment: It's possible the `WebBrowser` component has it's own native integration and isn't using the Swing event queue (directly), therefore it might not be possible to dispatch events in this. You may need to consider using `java.awt.Robot`

Comment: @MadProgrammer Ugh I was worried that might be the issue...  Is it possible to utilise `java.awt.Robot` in a way that doesn't control the Windows mouse?

Comment: Otherwise I'll need to find a new browser, independant mouse/keyboard control is a key feature to this application

Comment: I'm not familiar with the core API itself, but from what I can get out of the JavaDocs, no, don't think there is away to do it. No, interacting with the Mouse using Robot will effective its Phaeacian properties, that's kind of the point. You could "remember" where the mouse is and out it back after you've finished with it, but that might cause some other issues as well